# Unable to view BBcall attribute after sync to AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, microsoft-account

We unable to set BBcall attribute on AAD, is it by design or not ?

For example :

On premises AD :

https://morecovery.blob.core.windows.net/20170911/1.png

AAD :

https://morecovery.blob.core.windows.net/20170911/2.png

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Azure AD does not have the attribute of `BBcall`.

In your scenario, I think we can use Azure AD connect to sync your on-prem users' attributes to Azure AD.

More information about Azure AD connect to sync attribute to Azure, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-configure-filtering).

---

**Update:**

We can use Azure AD connect to sync custom attribute, like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason, but if we unable to view the attribute (BBcall) on AAD, do we have any solution which able to view special column on AAD?  - Eric

Comment: We can follow the link in my answer, to add an attribute to sync to AAD.

Comment: @wukuoming Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply and help :) so we only able to sync the custom attribute (BB call) to Azure but unable to show in Azure portal ? am I right ?

Comment: @wukuoming  if it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)